# How to redirect to another page in Python in CGIAr

Tags: python, cgi

**If I want to redirect the user from a cgi script to a HTML page using core libraries from the following:**

```
import cgi
```

Please could someone point me in the right direction. Nothing more.  Simply redirect from cgi script to html page.  How ever you would do this Python. If you have to physically write out the HTTP Response Headers to achieve this, then I would appreciate any info on how to do this. 
TIA

Andrew

Comment: Do you mean send a 302 response to the user's browser?  Or do you mean that one CGi script must call another CGI script within the server?

Comment: I would like to return a 302 response.  cheers

Comment: @REA_Andrew.  Please update your question so that it contains all the facts.  When updating it, please indicate what you're doing to build the HTTP headers that come back as part of the response.  Include code snippets if necessary to show how you're building the HTTP response (not all the HTML, but the headers)

Comment: You'll have to post more code so we can see where you're setting the status.  Or what library you're using.  Or something more tangible.

Comment: You'll have to post enough code that we can see what parts of cgi library you're using to start sending the page back to the browser.  You have to show how the response is started.  There are a lot of ways to sending the status code and the headers.  We need to see the actual code you're actually using to send the actual status code and actual headers.  302 is a status code.  Location is a header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to output one more header ("Status") in addition to the `Location` one, e.g.:

```
print "Status: 301 Moved",
print "Location:/wherever.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

**To redirect use Location header**

```
print "Location:URL\r\n"  # URL is the location where you want to redirct to
```

One point to remember is that location header should be written before any other print statements.If other print statements are written before it then the loaction header will be printed in the screen just as normal text.